# Having trouble advancing frame in AS3 to advance frames

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, button

I'm creating a quiz with buttons and I'm new to ActionScript 3.0, but very familiar with 2.0.

I have a variable inside of a MC called NextQuestion. When it reaches a certain frame, it changes to 1, then back to 0.

On the main timeline, when NextQuestion == 1, it's supposed to NextFrame();. I can't get it to work though, this is the last thing I'm having trouble with.

This is my main code with 4 buttons, 3 wrong, 1 right. The feedback MC plays an animation, and when it finishes, it sets the VAR NextQuestion to 1, which is supposed to make the main timeline advance to the NextFrame.

```
stop();

right.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rightClick1);
wrong1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, wrongClick1);
wrong2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, wrongClick1);
wrong3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, wrongClick1);
feedback1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, answerRight1);

function answerRight1()
{
    if (feedback1.NextQuestion == 1)
{
    trace(feedback1.NextQuestion);
    nextFrame();
}
else
{
    trace("do nothing");
}
 }

function rightClick1(ev:MouseEvent):void
{
trace(feedback1.NextQuestion);
feedback1.gotoAndPlay("right1");
}

function wrongClick1(ev:MouseEvent):void
{
trace("wrong");
feedback1.gotoAndPlay("wrong");
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nextFrame() method in AS3 doesn't loop trough your movieClips, it just set's the movie clip to the next frame provided there is a next frame, otherwise it does nothing.

you might want to re-write the nextFrame() to:

```
if (totalFrames == currentFrame)
{
    gotoAndStop(1); // or gotoAndPlay(1) if you need
}
else
{
    nextFrame();
}
```

Thats regarding why the movie clip might not start from the beginning.

Another thing that look weird is that you need a FRAME_ENTER event to check if the answer is correct. You must have a lot of spam in the output log. I'd recommend you to totally ditch the ENTER_FRAME event listener for this and do it all with the CLICKED event and dispatching the event from the feedback1 object.

As much as I understand the movie clip plays when you click a button and when the animation is over you want to either progress to next frame or do nothing. If so, on the feedback1 object add a following line in the end of animation for label "right1":

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("right"));
```

and instead of the line `feedback1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, answerRight1);` have:

```
feedback1.addEventListener("right", answerRight1);
```

That way you won't need to check the answer on every frame and you don't need to check if the answer is right or not, because when the `dispatchEvent(new Event("right"));` fires - it's always right.

Hope I didn't misunderstand your question :)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much for your help! I changed my Move to Next Question part of the code to look like this and it worked:
`function answerRight1(feedback1)
{
trace("next question")
gotoAndStop("q2");
}`